# Exception handling in Linq queries

Tags: c#, linq, exception, try-catch

I m using ...

```
tmpLst = (from e in App.lstAllChilds where e.Id == Id select e).ToList();
```

where `lstAllChilds` is the list, which contains some corrupted data as well.

So now i m tying to handle Try-Catch block inside this query.
Please help.

Comment: Is this Linq to Entities?  Linq to Objects?  What is the type of `lstAllChilds`?  I can't fathom what exception you are trying to catch exactly...  Have you actually gotten one?

Comment: its my custom list of class...   (List<OriginalPipe> App.lstAllChilds)

Comment: Exceptions are 'InvalidObjectException' and 'ArgumentNullException'

Comment: I m working on Autodesk's Revit API 2014.

Comment: @Nitin why dont u try a `try-catch` around the entire query? Should be enough.

Comment: Most likely `lstAllChilds` has not been initialized.  You should probably initialize it in the constructor of its class.  You can always check before you run the query for the case `if (lstAllChilds != null) ...` but I think in this case it simply shouldn't be null.

Comment: i cant.. @nawfal cause its i have to enumarate all elements inside that list.

Comment: @TrevorElliott .. its initialised and having count more than 100. :)

Comment: @Nitin Use the Visual Studio debugger to find out whether either `App`, `lstAllChilds`, or `e` is equal to null.  You can hover over the name of the variable when VS breaks on the exception being raised.  Most likely the real bug is one of those being null, they shouldn't be.  Catching a bug instead of fixing it isn't the right solution.

Comment: @TrevorElliott... previuosly i have handled null as well like.                                                   'tmpLst = (from e in App.lstAllChilds where e != null && e.Id == Id select e).ToList();' ,but as it is not the null exception i m getting.

Comment: @TrevorElliott .. U r absolutely right about. But In Revit Mep 2014, some element are getting invalid references when they changed inside revit document but as they are still present in C# list.(lstAllChilds)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the simplest change you can make to simply exclude items which are null or are raising an exception.

```
tmpLst = App.lstAllChilds.Where(e =>
{
    try
    {
        return e != null && e.Id == Id;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}).ToList();
```

But in my opinion you probably should investigate and solve the underlying problem.  This doesn't seem like a scenario where exceptions should be expected.

Answer (score 11):

In case if you just want to ignore "bad elements" then:

```
App.lstAllChilds.SkipExceptions().Where( e => e.Id == Id).ToList();
```

Extension method:

```
 public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> SkipExceptions<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values)
        {
            using (var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator())
            {
                bool next = true;
                while (next)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        next = enumerator.MoveNext();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (next) yield return enumerator.Current;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

So, here's the thing. There's language integrated query (Linq), and then there's yielded enumeration (a.k.a. Iterators).

Linq allows you to define an expression tree that is later executed by something that may or may not be C# (for example the expression could be translated into a SQL query). If you're writing linq there is a good chance your query provider (the thing that does the expression translation) does not support exception handling (much less whatever you're doing that throws exceptions).

Interators on the other hand (or "linq to objects") just ends up executing in C#, so you can just go wild with your exception handling.

For example w/ linq to objects you can do this:

```
var myList = new[] { "1", "2", "BARF", "3" };
var sum = myList.Select(str => {
  try {
    return Int32.Parse(str);
  } catch {
    return 0;
  }
}).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
```

If you're indeed doing linq to objects, and you just want to skip elements where your source IEnumerable threw an exception check out Vladimir Gondarev's answer.

The important thing to understand however, is that the anonymous function we just passed to that Select call **is not an Expression (an uncompiled expression tree)**, it is a Func (a delegate pointing to compiled c# code), which means that it will run in the .Net process, even if we replaced myList with a linq to entities table (or some other linq provider). The reason for this is that the C# expression syntax does not support blocks, nor does it support try-catch. Unsurprisingly, given that, the SQL-style Linq statements (from xxx select yyy) also do not support try-catch blocks.

However, just because the C# expression syntax doesn't support it doesn't mean you can't do it. But, to be clear, **I do not recommend doing this** because I highly doubt there is a QueryProvider in existence that supports it (aside from the linq to objects provider). For the curious here's how you would create a lambda expression that contains a try-catch block.

```
var parseMethod = typeof(Int32).GetMethod("Parse", new[] { typeof(String) });
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(String));
var selectExp =
    Expression.Lambda<Func<String, Int32>>(
        Expression.TryCatch(
            Expression.Call(parseMethod, param),
            Expression.Catch(typeof(Exception), Expression.Constant(0))
        ),
        param
    );
var sum = myList.Select(selectExp).Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
```

So when somebody implements a QueryProvider backed by a store that supports exception handling, you could use this.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what exactly you are trying to achieve:

1. Return the list except "broken" items.

   - You can try using a `Where` clause to check and filter them out:

     ```
     App.lstAllChilds.Where(x => IsValidNode(x, Id)).ToList();
     ```

     Apparently you need to implement `IsValidNode` which should check for `null`, if it can throw an `InvalidObjectException` (not sure if you can easily detect it but you can always wrap it in a try-catch block) and `Id` equality. Like that:

     ```
     private bool IsValidNode(Child c, int id)
     {
         if (x == null) return false;
         try {
             return c.Id == id;
         }
         catch (InvalidObjectException)
         {

         }
         return false;
     }
     ```
2. Return an empty list if there are any broken items.

   - Just wrap the entire thing in a try-catch block